# Replacing column names with own names

Tags: r, text, vector, dataframe, time-series

I have produced a text file in R using 
    write.table(matrix(z,byrow=F,nrow=12),"monthly.txt",row.names=T,col.names=T)
which looks like [produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxfeg.jpg)

I would want the table to be however like this [desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSreD.jpg). How should I modify the code so that V's and the numbers get replaced by the year and month name such as the image 2?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the column and row names using the functions colnames() and rownames()

```
mat <- matrix(z,byrow=F,nrow=12)
colnames(mat) <- c("list","of","names","you","want","on","the", "top")
rownames(mat) <- c("list","of","names","you","want","on","the", "side")

write.table(mat,"monthly.txt",row.names=T,col.names=T)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and looks like there is a new error    "Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Months", "1986", "1987", "1988",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent". The row names seem to be okay however. I would also not want the "" signs before the headings. Any ideas on how to solve this error please?

Comment: Thats becasue you are trying to add N+1 column names to N columns. Drop the "Months". It is not needed, from the row names, whoever is reading this table will be more than capable of telling that the rows are months without a label explicitly telling them

Comment: Make sure the length of the vector you are passing to colnames is the same length as the number of columns. Also please see the help page about write.table by doing ?write.table   The answer to your "" follow up is there but I will let you find it as practice to using the documentation

Comment: I got everything fixed but just one question is that why are my data not properly organized like the data for a year should be listed exactly according to the month in that column. I see that data points are scattered probably because of improper placing between the columns? Can this be fixed somehow?